# Phonegap Back Button: Back and Exit

Tags: button, cordova, exit, back

> Phonegap: 2.9.0
>
> Android: 4.4.2

I want use the "Back Button": if current page is not Home Page, Back, else Exit the APP, but it dose not works, why?

Here is my code: **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("http://www.mydomain.com", 0);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && appView.canGoBack())
        {
            appView.goBack();
            return false;
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            dialog();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    protected void dialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Exit The APP?");
        builder.setTitle("Are You Sure");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }
            });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help and best wishes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better, handle the event inside your cordova app, by wiring up an event listener...

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onBackKeyDown, false);
```

then, write your own logic...

```
onBackKeyDown: function() {
   ... insert your logic here...
}
```

This answer was inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146231/android-device-buttons-and-phonegap-cordova).  Please acknowledge which one works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)  to prevent using the back button, but it doesn't seem to work the same in 4.4.2, using cordova 3.3.  Maybe just move your existing code into this event...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   ... insert your relevant onkeydown logic here.
}
```